# How to add connect Custom Login with the Redux Store

Tags: react-admin

I have created a custom Login page in a new react-admin app and intend to login. How do i access the userLogin action from the store.

I tried wrapping the root component in a provider but can't access the store.

Currently using the login example

```
class MyLoginPage extends Component {
    submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // gather your data/credentials here
        const credentials = { };

        // Dispatch the userLogin action (injected by connect)
        this.props.userLogin(credentials);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={this.props.theme}>
                <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
                ...
                </form>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
};


export default connect(undefined, { userLogin })(MyLoginPage);
```

I expect to retrieve the userLogin action from react-admin and push to the redux store

Comment: This seems like the correct usage of `userLogin`. But it takes a second parameters with an url to redirect to.

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/74fd40339ce5007a1148883d1d808bbb107500bd/packages/ra-core/src/actions/authActions.ts#L12-L19

Comment: @Kmaschta Understood but the connect from react-redux is the one with the issue, Trying to connect with react-admin's store but don't know how

Comment: Can you try setting up a codesandbox showing your issue ?